# Resources for practicing Maths

Tags: online-resources

There are a few posts on Resources for *learning* maths. But I am looking for *practice* questions preferably with solutions. Are there any you would recommend? Online or Books

I am currently a Computer Science University student, 4 Maths modules I require are

- Introductory Mathematics (Basic Maths like Partial Fractions, Trigo, Differentiation, Integration, Complex numbers etc)
- Linear Algebra
- Discrete Maths
- Calculus for Computing
- Probability & Stats

Thus resources (practice questions) for these topics will be preferred

Comment: The Schaum's Outlines series are filled with examples and practice problems.

Answer (score 1):

For practice questions in the introductory mathematics, check out Khan Academy. I haven't come across anything as good yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://maths-for-all.co.uk/engineering-mathematics/
The tests are in red and you can enter abc as your name,12 as your student number and school as your email address.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Beestar. Its user-friendly interface and interactive can make the learning experience more engaging and enjoyable. It emphasizes skill development through interactive practice. The platform offers a variety of exercises, quizzes, and challenges that help students enhance their critical thinking, problem-solving, and analytical skills.